# Classic GNOME Flashback in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic

Till now I was working with Ubuntu 16.04, with classic GNOME flashback (I don't remember where did I install it from).

Now I moved finally to 20.04, and tried to install the same, but somehow it looks much less elegant to me.

While this is how it looks in **16.04**:
[image: Ubuntu 16.04 Classic GNOME flashback]

This is how it looks after installing it on **20.04**:
[image: Ubuntu 20.04 Classic GNOME flashback]

I wonder whether this is how it is, or should I install another package or something.

Comment: The second screenshot (20.04) shows the default theme, look & feel, the first (16.04) shows a dark theme which isn't and never was the default. So, besides not remembering where/how did you installed in 16.04, maybe you also forgot that you themed it? Something like this https://pod.g3l.org/posts/56781 perhaps. Suggestion: Install Ubuntu-MATE to avoid (a lot of) headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try MATE as in Ubuntu MATE. Install it with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

then reboot, login to MATE session and enjoy classical traditional desktop without bells and whistles.

Customization is possible by running MATE Tweak after installation - you can switch Panel layout to Traditional layout (as in GNOME 2) -

[image: Traditional MATE on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS]

or try more modern layouts which suite your needs.

---

Additional note:

- you can make a screenshot with opened context menus by running MATE Screenshot with timeout in interactive mode by `mate-screenshot -i` command.
- you may want to read [Ubuntu MATE Guide](https://guide.ubuntu-mate.org/) to know Ubuntu MATE system.
- you may want to read [MATEwiki](https://wiki.mate-desktop.org/) to know MATE desktop.
- you may want to talk with Ubuntu MATE Community on the [corresponding site](https://ubuntu-mate.community/).

Comment: Is the orange ambiance theme still available? OP might be looking for it.

Comment: Theme adjusting is possible from MATE Appearance properties (`mate-appearance-properties`). Orange icons are available. Theming is possible too, but this topic is wide, I do not think we need to discuss it here.

Comment: Is there a good place to start understanding what is MATE exactly and how to manage it? I see many differences from Traditional Ubuntu I had till now...

Comment: Check https://guide.ubuntu-mate.org/ along with https://wiki.mate-desktop.org/.

Comment: @guyaloni Alternatively, you can ask a new question about Ubuntu MATE when you have one :-)

Comment: Well, I would say that my question is basically what is the difference between Ubuntu, Ubuntu-Mate and Ubuntu-Mate-desktop... I found many posts, but all of them are quite old.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to use old theme:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Ambiance'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'ubuntu-mono-dark'
```

But I don't know how good/bad old theme works in 20.04.

Comment: Why down vote? User noticed changes in look in newer version... It is because 20.04 has different theme and old look can be restored by changing theme.