# Ubuntu mate shortcuts for area-screenshot and change-layout

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, mate, ubuntu-mate

After many years of working with Ubuntu, I finally installed Ubuntu Mate desktop [as I was recommended](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379291/114233).

At the moment I cannot manage to active the following keyboard shortcuts, which were very useful for me till now:

- **Take a selected-area screenshot:**
  The shift+ImpPt (PrtScn) combination opens a 'take screenshot' pop-up which allows me to perform this action.
  However, I used to have a shortcut which opened directly the area screenshot cursor, now with this combination I have to perform another step.
- **Change keyboard layout:**
  In System->Preferences->Hardware->keyboard, under the layout tab, I found the "Options..." button than has inside the item "Switching to another layout". I tried a couple of combinations but it doesn't work for me (Alt+Shift, Ctrl+Shift, ...).
  Just to be clear, I am lookign for a shortcut that will toggle between 3 different layouts I have.

============= Edit ===========
More information:

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard 
XKBLAYOUT=es,gb,il
XKBVARIANT=,,
BACKSPACE=guess
```

```
$ dpkg -l | grep ibus
ii  gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64                         1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1                     amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - introspection data
ii  ibus                                          1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1                     amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - core
ii  ibus-data                                     1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1                     all          Intelligent Input Bus - data files
ii  ibus-gtk:amd64                                1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1                     amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - GTK2 support
ii  ibus-gtk3:amd64                               1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1                     amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - GTK3 support
ii  ibus-table                                    1.9.25-1                              all          table engine for IBus
ii  libgusb2:amd64                                0.3.4-0.1                             amd64        GLib wrapper around libusb1
ii  libibus-1.0-5:amd64                           1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1                     amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - shared library
ii  libusageenvironment3:amd64                    2020.01.19-1build1                    amd64        multimedia RTSP streaming library (UsageEnvironment classes)
ii  libusb-1.0-0:amd64                            2:1.0.23-2build1                      amd64        userspace USB programming library
ii  libusbmuxd6:amd64                             2.0.1-2                               amd64        USB multiplexor daemon for iPhone and iPod Touch devices - library
ii  python3-ibus-1.0                              1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1                     all          Intelligent Input Bus - introspection overrides for Python (Python 3)
```

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep xkb
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general default-group -1
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general known-file-list @as []
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general disable-sysconfig-changed-warning false
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general update-handlers @as []
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general group-per-window true
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general duplicate-leds false
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general disable-indicator false
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general layout-names-as-group-names true
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general load-extra-items false
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general handle-indicators false
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options @as []
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources [('xkb', 'es'), ('xkb', 'gb'), ('xkb', 'il')]
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd layouts @as []
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd options @as []
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd model ''
org.freedesktop.ibus.panel xkb-icon-rgba '#415099'
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.indicator show-flags false
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.indicator background-color ''
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.indicator font-family ''
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.indicator foreground-color ''
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.indicator secondary 0
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.preview width -1
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.preview y -1
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.preview height -1
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.preview x -1
org.freedesktop.ibus.general xkb-latin-layouts ['ara', 'bg', 'cz', 'dev', 'gr', 'gur', 'in', 'jp(kana)', 'mal', 'mkd', 'ru', 'ua']
org.freedesktop.ibus.general preload-engines ['xkb:es::spa', 'xkb:us::eng', 'xkb:il::heb']
org.freedesktop.ibus.general engines-order ['xkb:es::spa', 'xkb:il::heb', 'xkb:us::eng']
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot manage the following keyboard shortcuts"? What do you mean by "direct shortcut"? Are you trying to set Ctrl+Shift as keyboard layout switch? Have you consulted with https://guide.ubuntu-mate.org/#page-shortcuts  about shortcuts?

Comment: Just edited my question, hope now it is clear.

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard` ; `dpkg -l | grep ibus` and `gsettings list-recursively | grep xkb` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert, just added the information you asked.

Answer (score 3):

To disable **interactive area screenshot** you have to edit the command which executes on <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> by using command below:

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.keybinding-commands command-2 "/bin/sh -c 'sleep .1;mate-screenshot --area'"
```

Reverting to defaults is possible by

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.keybinding-commands command-2 "mate-screenshot --area --interactive"
```

If you do not want to change the command for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, add your own custom keyboard shortcut for custom `/bin/sh -c 'sleep .1;mate-screenshot --area'` command from Keyboard Shortcuts (or run `mate-keybinding-properties` directly).

---

Then **about keyboard layouts**. You have to open MATE Keyboard Preferences from MATE Control Center (or run `mate-keyboard-properties` directly) and then add keyboard layouts on the *Layouts* tab, click *Options* to set *Switching to another layout* to the needed value like *Alt+Shift*. This will allow you to switch between keyboard layouts by the specified shortcut in cycle.

Note: if you have a problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+*other_key* interference, then you have to add [my PPA to the system](https://launchpad.net/%7Enrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys) (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/66509) for details).

Comment: I understand that you recommend disabling interactive area screenshot in order to access the default screenshot? In this case, how can I enable it if I want to do it later on?

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert, switching layout is solved. 
Regarding to **interactive area screenshot**, actually I would like to add a different shortcut for it, but I do no find where to add it in **Keyboard Preferences** - can you please tell me how to add it?

Comment: BTW, I do have a probelm with `Ctrl` + `Shift` combination. I set in the terminal the **Reset and Clear** shortcut to be `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `E`, and it doesn't work (I get an underlined lowercase `e` and then what I type is added to it). I added the PPA you mentioned, but still have the same problem... :-(

Comment: I do not know your current keymap, but on some of them "underlined lowercase" means unicode input. So I would suggest to undo your Ctrl+Shift+E shortcut. "Reset and Clear" on english keyboard layout is easily accessible by Alt+T, L. I would recommend to remember this default shortcut, it is simple. Adding custom keyboard shortcuts is possible from `mate-keybinding-properties` (MATE Keyboard Shortcuts) - you click Add, specify Name and Command, then add Shortcut for this freshly created line.