# Custom shortcut to "mate-screenshot -a"

Tags: 20.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, screenshot

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with mate desktop.  I also use an external keyboard - [logitech keyboard k850](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/combos/mk850-wireless-keyboard-mouse.920-008219.html) which unfortunately do not have the print-screen key :-(

In the native keyboard of my laptop the combination <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> opens the (mate?) screenshot dialog:

[image]

I am interested in having a selected-area-screenshot shortcut which is not using the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>, better if this is a shortcut to `mate-screenshot -a` (directly selected area).

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I have just figured out that there is a screenshot key on my keyboard, which is <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd> (which has a camera icon on it)...

So in order to achieve it, I use:

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd>

This will open this dialog box:

[image]

It is one step more than using `mate-screenshot -a`, yet - it works.

Comment: You can always define your own custom shortcut that calls the command *you* want.

Comment: Sounds great, can you please explain how?

Comment: I do not have Mate. Just the standard way to add a custom shortcut in your desktop environment - look up the basic documentation if needed. Disable the standard shortcut defined for print screen first.

Comment: @guyaloni Custom keyboard shortcuts maybe defined in Keyboard Shortcuts of MATE Control Center (`mate-keybinding-properties`) . Also see our [previous Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379984/66509).

Answer (score 1):

You simply add a custom shortcut via the MATE Keyboard shortcuts settings app:

1. **Open shortcuts window:** System->Preferences->Hardware->Keyboard Shortcuts
2. **Create new shortcut:** Click the *Add* button. Set the name you like e.g. `Area Screenshot` and set the Command to `mate-screenshot -a`. Then click Apply
3. **Set the screenshot you want:** Double click where it says *Disabled* and press your preferred Key combo, e.g. *"Ctrl+T"*

**Done!**

Comment: From some reason the command is not fired....

Comment: mmh strange, what is the output of this command? `dconf dump /org/mate/desktop/keybindings/`

Comment: `[custom0]
action='mate-screenshot -a'
binding='<Primary>t'
name='Area Screenshot'
`